# Minimize Current Sensing Loss in LED Driver

Tags: led, driver

[image]

Design voltages and currents:

Vo = 100V. Iout = 50mA. Po = 5W.

R4 is the output current sense resistor. The reference voltage for the error amplifier is 2.5 V which implies that under the target output current, this resistor will be 50 Ohm. With a current of 50 mA, this resistor will be dissipating 125 mW of power!

My application is for just 5W output power which means that 125 mW is 2.5% of this! How can I minimize the power dissipation? Will I have to move to a different topology (single stage PF is important)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a smaller resistor and an op-amp amplifier to boost the signal across R4. If you had a x10 op-amp gain stage, R4 effectively becomes 10x smaller. Don't use any crappy op-amp though - I suspect you'll need something reasonably fast to avoid potential oscillation problems. The op-amp also needs inputs and outputs to work down to the earth rail (as per your circuit. You should be able to steal half a mA from Vcc to power the op-amp. Maybe consider an AD8605 (there will be plenty of others of course).

Comment: Unfortunately, this sounds like an expensive fix. Would going to primary side regulation be better?

Comment: You never mentioned cost was an issue in your question and if all you have done is look up how much an AD8605 costs, I suggest you do a bit more digging around. I mentioned that chip because it sprang to mind.

Comment: You could add two resistors to raise the R4 voltage maybe 1.5 volts. This means R4 could reduce to 40% of its previous value. You might be able to bias it a tad more but without looking into the detail of the chip this is hard to say.